# Application Designing guide line for interaction between Win & Web application

Tags: c#, webforms, interaction

our company has website which has been developed by asp.net web form and hosted in shared location in ORCSWEB company. web site has a specific page from where people upload their CV. when a new CV is uploaded then few entry stored in database and cv file stored in folder where our web site hosted. database is also maintain at ORCSWEB end.

i have developed a win service which run in our office and it periodically query the remote database for new CV. if found any then it will download that CV file in local machine and as well as remote cv data from remote db to local db and update a filed called isDownloaded=1 in remote db as a result next time that same records will not be queried or checked.

the whole web part and win service part working fine but now our IT head want to change in web & win service logic bit.

he wants that when any new candidate upload their CV through our site then a notification will be send to our win service after 5 minute from web apps. after getting notification from web apps then win service will download the cv.

now i am not being able to thing how to design our web apps which can  send some notification directly to our win service which is running in our office because there is no physical connection or accessibility between two pc where our win service & web apps are running. our win service is running in our private network and web apps is hosted in another company machine.

some told me this can be achieve through WCF but did not guide me how to develop this kind of bridge between win service & web apps through which communication will be possible.

i know lots of experienced & scholar developer always monitor this site and that is why i like to ask them how this problem can be sorted. what logic i need to use to send notification from our web apps to win service.

so please guide me with all possible way to develop a system which solve our purpose. discuss all possible way like wcf or anything else which can be use to develop apps which enable me to achieve our goal. looking for elaborate discussion and guidance. if possible give me few sample code & links which give me idea to write code for our situation. thanks

Comment: Why are you starting each sentence with a lower case?

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs